# How can I create a C++ project in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I was new to Visual Studio and I want it to debug some of my c++ files.

The VS 2010 Ultimate was already installed in my lab system.

Now to debug after referring to internet and also here I came to know that we need to start a new project as below

File -> New -> Project -> Visual C# -> Win32 -> Win32 Console application

But in my VS there was no Win32 under Visual C# but there was Windows in which there was Console application, which I selected.

Then we need to add the C++ files under the source files directory. But I didn't find any such directory in this console application.

Is there any problem with installation or configuration.
Can anyone please help me.

Comment: The only way I know to add c++ code to a c# project is by compiling the c++ code into a DLL first. I don't think you can mix them in the same project. Maybe create a c++ project?

Comment: C# and C++ are about as similar as Bruce Wayne and Bruce Willis. Which language are you trying to use?

Comment: @kfsone *Outstanding* simile'. Though I always thought in his Die Hard prime Willis would have made an awesome Bruce Wayne =P

Comment: Probably `File -> New -> Project -> Visual C++ -> Win32 -> Win32 Console application` would have been a better start.

Comment: And of course this option is only available if the C++ components of Visual Studio where installed in the first place (which might not be the case here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct path to start a win32 C++ console project is

```
File -> New -> Project -> Visual C++ -> Win32 -> Win32 Console application
```

and if you don ´t find path it mean that you.have a custom setup.
find your setup DVD and/or use Add and Remove program to " modify " the setup. When installation program ask for the component you need check the C++  box. finish the setup and and after you will have a specific section for c++ project ....

Comment: I modified  some of the setting and it worked. may be the one installed it earlier in the system may not done it properly. Thank you